# SharePoint Online in IE11 webpart is missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, internet-explorer

[image]

Hello how to do I fix this problem. A user can't see web part displaying new feed which is meant to show next to title links. How do I fix this problem. they are using IE 11

Answer (score 0):

Check if the web part displays on the page in another browser such as Chrome.

Try to [open the page in compatible mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17472/windows-internet-explorer-11-fix-site-display-problems-compatibility-v#ie=ie-11) and see if it works.

IE > Settings > Compatibility settings > Add the site to the Compatibility View list and display intranet sites in compatibility view.

In addition, press F12 to open the F12 Developer Tools and go to the Emulation tool. Test with 10 mode or lower mode to see if the issue still exists.

Comment: I followed your steps still no luck :(